# Using TinyMCE with Django, I see ImportError: Cannot import name simplejson

Tags: python, json, django

I'm using Django and TinyMCE on Windows. When I run the following in the command prompt:

> ```
> python manage.py runserver
> ```

I get

> ```
> ImportError: Cannot import name simplejson
> ```

Below is the entire console output including traceback that I got (from [Screenshot here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1M9bBw5nAZKEgkoUzfKqK5ygvXmoJPb3T3Knpl9hpFWs/edit?usp=sharing))

Has anyone got any tips?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>easy_install sinplejson
searching for simplejson
Best match: sinplejson 3.7.3
Processing simp1ejson-3.7.3-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
sinplejson 3.7.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Using C:\python2?\lib\site-packages\sinp1ejson-3.7.3-pg2.7-win-and64.egg
processing dependencies for simplejson
finished processing dependencies for simplejson

C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\home\genesis_book

C:\Home\Genesis_Book>python manage.pg runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py". line 13. in (nodule)
    execute_from_comnand_1ine(sys.argu)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py". Line 338. in execute_from_conmand_1ine
    uti1ity.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py". Line 312. in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py". line 18. in setup
    apps.popu1ate(settings.INSTﬂLLED_BPP8)
  Fi1e "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.pg". line 138. in populate
    app_config.import_mode1s(a11_mode1s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py". line 198. in import_models
    se1f.mode1s_modu1e = import_modu1e(mode1s_modu1e_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py". line 37. in import_modu1e
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Home\Genesis_Book\webapp\tinymce\nodels.py". line 6. in (module)
    from tinymce import widgets as tinymce_widgets
  File "C:\Home\Genesis_Book\webapp\tinymce\widgets.py". line 19. in (nodule)
    from django.uti1s import simplejson
ImportError: cannot import name simplejson
```

#### Update

People have suggested that I use `easy_install simplejson`, but I still get the error - I've added the output following that stage to my screenshot and the console output above.

Comment: Can you copy and paste?

Comment: Import `json` instead?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! The way you've asked your question, with the main bit in the title and the Traceback in a picture embedded in a presentation is particularly unlikely to help future users, which is one of the main aims of the site, or to get you all the help you could get.  See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on how to structure a good question here. In this particular case, can you copy and paste the error from your terminal into the question and take the text from the title into the body of the question?  Good luck!

Comment: @JesseQuarum In the interests of helping you to see what I mean, I've got the traceback from the picture using OCR and added it to your question, made the title more descriptive and the question more focused. I wouldn't normally do that and shouldn't have to, but there is a reasonable question here.  You got answers that didn't help because you didn't follow the advice to improve your question.  I hope my edits show how you could have done this - please do have a look at the changes I made  so you can see what to do next time and also proof read the traceback.

Comment: P.S. I've also given you an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of `django-tinymce` is incompatible with your version of `django`.  [`django.utils.simplejson` has been deprecated as per the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.5/#simplejson-deprecation), but your version of `django-tinymce` is still trying to import it.

The module `simplejson` installed by `easy_install simplejson` is a different module and hence has no effect as you have found.

The fix to `django-tinymce` was applied in [this code change](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce/commit/bbdeb13163ef380f7d6bbab64723ad18fb532f8a) on 9th July 2013.  I don't know how you have an old version on your system, but this is what you need to upgrade. It resides in `C:\Home\genesis_book\webapp\tinymce` on your system.  I suspect it has been bundled with some application that you have downloaded, or you have included it in an old project and not upgraded it.

To fix this - you need to replace at least `views.py` and `widgets.py` in that directory with the versions found here https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce/tree/bbdeb13163ef380f7d6bbab64723ad18fb532f8a/tinymce.

**Massive caveat** that's not a clean way to upgrade, but without further information about how exactly django-tinymce was installed on your system with an old version, it is the best I can do.

Answer (score 3):

From django 1.7

> The module django.utils.simplejson will be removed. The standard library provides json which should be used instead.

To install

```
easy_install simplejson
```

Comment: I have simplejson installed but it still is giving me the error

Comment: @JesseQuarum I told you - `import json`.

Comment: You will get error, since it is importing from django.Solution 1. can edit it(if can) 2. Downgrade django version

Comment: I added another pic to the link.  I have done everything you all have said

Comment: Now which django version are you using ?

Comment: Please **stop** posting pictures in links, and post the actual error messages in your question.

Comment: @JesseQuarum don't use a picture - copy the text of the traceback off your console into the question.  That is where the key to your error resides, but people will not be able to help you unless you do that.

Comment: @JesseQuarum it occurs to me that you may not know how to do that. I see you are on windows.  in the command prompt, right click and click `Mark` on the menu.  Select the top left of where you want to copy.  Drag down to the bottom right.  Right click again. The text you want is now on the clipboard - just paste it into the question as normal.  Apologies if you already knew this.